# How does github choose an user's popular repositories?

Tags: github

Github has this "Popular repositories" list on each user's profile. I would like to know how they do the math to get to that list. Is it the number of views that counts? The number of commits? Number of clones, forks,...?

The list seems random-ish to me as there are cases where popular repositories are chosen out of a list of repos with the same stats. For example, a relatively new user that has 10 repos with 0 stars and forks will have 5 repos chosen to feature the "Popular repositories" list. What is the criteria?

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/57372/how-does-github-select-and-order-which-repositories-appear-under-popular-reposi

Comment: Thanks! Please answer this question so I can mark it as what I was looking for. @lemonhead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Github Help Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/viewing-contributions-on-your-profile-page/):

> This section displays your repositories with the most watchers.

For further detail on the ordering of the popular repos, see [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/57372/how-does-github-select-and-order-which-repositories-appear-under-popular-reposi)